# Flash or Silverlight video in Razor?

Tags: asp.net, razor

How can I play a Flash or Silverlight video in ASP .NET Razor? I can't find any information on this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For flash you could use the [SWFObject script](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/) and for Silverlight [use the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: @Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen, *by videos*, do you mean applications or you mean videos :-)?

Comment: Videos, as in a player that can play the video too.

Comment: @Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen, you may checkout the [Silverlight Video Player](http://silverlight30.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Razor is just a server-side language that creates HTML.

You can embed videos the same way you embed videos in static HTML.